# (installing pip) AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Command'

Tags: python, bash, pip

I am trying to get started in programming but I am having a lot of trouble installing pip so that then I can install other modules. I have been trying to use

```
sudo easy_install pip
```

but I am greeted with this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/easy_install", line 11, in <module>
load_entry_point('setuptools==36.3.0', 'console_scripts', 'easy_install')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 564, in load_entry_point
return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2662, in load_entry_point
return ep.load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2316, in load
return self.resolve()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2322, in resolve
module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
from setuptools.extern.six.moves import filter, map
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/setuptools/__init__.py", line 160, in <module>
monkey.patch_all()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/setuptools/monkey.py", line 48, in patch_all
distutils.core.Command = setuptools.Command
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Command'
```

Google hasn't been too helpful in trying to figure out what is wrong. This error comes up any time I attempt to install pip or to install setup tools.

Comment: The error output appears incomplete, there's no closing quote after `Command`. Can you add the rest of the error message?

Comment: That is the entire message I must have left out the last quote when copying it over.

Comment: Try installing a package manager, like [conda](https://conda.io/docs/). This will take care of dependencies, and install locally, so you don't need to use `sudo` and possibly get in trouble that way.

Comment: What steps are you following to install pip? Have you installed easy_install first? See [link](https://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2010/02/how-install-pip-ubuntu/)

Comment: the "sudo easy_install pip" command is the only method I have tries thus far. @deaspo

Comment: See the link I have added for the full install in ubuntu